# HLSL: predefined variables

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, hlsl

does HLSL have predefined variables for common matrices like GLSL has?

i am looking for `gl_ProjectionMatrix` and `gl_ModelViewMatrix` respectively?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't unfortunatly.

You have to define them youself and send them to the shader manually from your application using shader parameters.

Comment: The same behaviour has been introduced in OpenGL-3 (and higher) core profile.